# How can i select a specific column of Entity Dynamically? JPA/querydsl

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

can i implement the following through querydsl or Spring Data JPA?

1. I have a Table(Column: A,B,C)
2. I want to select a specific column of Entity(Table)
3. Specific columns are defined as List. (Each element matches column name)

Thank you.

Comment: would you intend to project in the same entity??

Comment: @tuhin47 sure. I want to work on the same project.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "select ?1 from Tablename")
public List<String> readAColumn(String columnname);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your service you could have a method similar to

```
private List<Object[]> selectByColumnNames(ArrayList<String> columnNames) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select " + StringUtils.join(columnNames, ",") + " from YourEntityName")
            .getResultList();
}
```